# How to view an update in view with codeigniter using mvc structure?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to Codeigniter but not on the MVC framework. I got a view where it shows a list of applicants. I want to update the applicant. When I click an update button on the applicants row or by simply clicking the status(using  tag).

The goal is to update the applicants status only (not set, passed, failed, etc.). I can work with new codes and functions if my codes given cannot be understood.

****model**** "model name = activefile.php"

```
function updateApplicant($id, $fname, $mname, $lname, $gender, $bday, $num, $addr, $school, $crs, $srcstrat, $psdate, $psstatus, $date) {

    //  $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data = array(
        'fname' => $fname,
        'mname' => $mname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'birthday' => $bday,
        'contactno' => $num,
        'address' => $addr,
        'institution' => $school,
        'course' => $crs,
        'src_strat' => $srcstrat,
        'exam_date' => $date,
        'ps_date' => $psdate,
        'ps_status' => $psstatus,
    );

    $this->hrrecdb->select('*', 'activefile');
    $this->hrrecdb->where('active_file_id', $id);
    $this->hrrecdb->update('active_file ', $data);

}
```

****controller**** "controller name = hrrecruitment.php"

```
public function updateApplicant($id) {

    $fname = $this->input->post('fn');
    $mname = $this->input->post('mn');
    $lname = $this->input->post('ln');
    $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
    $bday = $this->input->post('bday');
    $num = $this->input->post('num');
    $addr = $this->input->post('addr');
    $school = $this->input->post('school');
    $crs = $this->input->post('crs');


    if ($this->input->post('srcstrat') == 'emprefopt') {
        if ($this->input->post('empref_autocomplete_label') && $this->input->post('empref')) {
            $srcstrat = 'empref_' . $this->input->post('empref');
        } else {
            $srcstrat = 'empref_' . $this->input->post('emprefhid');
        }
    } else if ($this->input->post('srcstrat') == 'others') {
        $srcstrat = 'others_' . $this->input->post('others');
    } else {
        $srcstrat = $this->input->post('srcstrat');
    }

    $psdate = $this->input->post('psdatehid');
    $psstatus = $this->input->post('psstatus');

    if ($psstatus != 'Not Set' && $psdate == '0000-00-00') {
        $psdate = date('Y-m-d');
    }
    $date = $this->input->post('exam');

    if ($date != '0000-00-00' && $date) {
        $this->add_recruitment($id, $date);
    }

    if ($this->input->post('pscheck') == 'changed') {
        $this->Activefile->updateHistory($id, $this->user->get_fullName());
    }
    $this->Activefile->updateApplicant($id, $fname, $mname, $lname, $gender, $bday, $num, $addr, $school, $crs, $srcstrat, $psdate, $psstatus, $date);

    redirect(base_url() . 'hrrecruitment/applicants/all');
    $this->edit_info($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what question you are asking. But I do see that the model has a slight flaw in these three lines

```
$this->hrrecdb->select('*', 'activefile');
$this->hrrecdb->where('active_file_id', $id);
$this->hrrecdb->update('active_file ', $data);
```

The first line is not important to what you're doing. A call to `select` is for, well... *select*ing data. Remove this line.

The second and third lines can be done in one call

```
$this->hrrecdb->update('active_file ', $data, array('active_file_id' => $id));
```

The function `update` accepts a third argument - a WHERE clause. So, the argumnent `array('active_file_id' => $id)` is saying the same thing as `$this->hrrecdb->where('active_file_id', $id);`  Less typing is good, yes?

The controller has one obvious problem at the end.

```
redirect(base_url() . 'hrrecruitment/applicants/all');
$this->edit_info($id);
```

The last line will never be called because the function `redirect` does not return. Instead it sends the browser to a new page and script execution ends. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with the call to `$this->edit_info($id)` but it's never going to run.

Tip 1: The function `base_url()` can accept URI segments. So, use it like this.

```
base_url('hrrecruitment/applicants/all')
```

Tip 2: The `redirect()` function will figure out the `base_url` for you so all you really need is

```
redirect('hrrecruitment/applicants/all');
```

Tip 3: When you find yourself writing the exact same call again and again then capture the return and use that instead. For example:

```
$srcstrat = $this->input->post('srcstrat');
if($srcstrat == 'emprefopt')
{
    if($this->input->post('empref_autocomplete_label') && $this->input->post('empref'))
    {
        $srcstrat = 'empref_'.$this->input->post('empref');
    }
    else
    {
        $srcstrat = 'empref_'.$this->input->post('emprefhid');
    }
}
elseif($srcstrat == 'others')
{
    $srcstrat = 'others_'.$this->input->post('others');
}
```